# How to read editor text before cursor position to match specific words?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect when the cursor has moved somewhere immediately after a specific strings ... I can do it only for I have one string , But when I have more than one I cant't matched ... If I have one string like : "color:" then the code to match the word is :

```
<!-- Create a simple CodeMirror instance -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
<script>

  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
    lineNumbers: true
  });

  //Catch cursor change event
  editor.on('cursorActivity',function(e){
    var line = e.doc.getCursor().line,   //Cursor line
        ch = e.doc.getCursor().ch,       //Cursor character
        stringToMatch = "color:",
        n = stringToMatch.length,
        stringToTest = e.doc.getLine(line).substr(Math.max(ch - n,0),n);

    if (stringToTest == stringToMatch) console.log("SUCCESS!!!");
  });

</script>
```

But when I have array of strings like (var array=["one","three","five"]) and I want to match any word in this array I can't do it ... so any body can help I try a lot and failed

NOTE : the code above I take it from : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622128/codemirror-how-to-read-editor-text-before-or-after-cursor-position)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for matching one of several words:

```
var line = e.doc.getCursor().line,   //Cursor line
    ch = e.doc.getCursor().ch,       //Cursor character
    // Select all characters before cursor
    stringToTest = e.doc.getLine(line).substr(0, ch), 
    // Array with search words: escape characters for use in regular expression:
    array=["one","three","five"].map( s => s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') );

// Join words with OR (|) and require they match just before the cursor 
// (i.e. at end of string: $)
if (stringToTest.match(new RegExp('('+array.join('|')+')$'))) console.log("SUCCESS!!!");
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
  lineNumbers: true
});

//Catch cursor change event
editor.on('cursorActivity',function(e){
  var line = e.doc.getCursor().line,   //Cursor line
      ch = e.doc.getCursor().ch,       //Cursor character
      // Select all characters before cursor
      stringToTest = e.doc.getLine(line).substr(0, ch), 
      // Array with search words: escape characters for use in regular expression:
      array=["one","three","five"]
          .map( s => s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') );

  // Join words and require they match just before the cursor 
  // (i.e. at end of string: $)
  if (stringToTest.match(new RegExp('(' + array.join('|') + ')$')))
    console.log("SUCCESS!!!");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.19.0/codemirror.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.19.0/codemirror.js"></script>
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks for help you are great that what I want  @trincot